# Loading a custom Yii Component

Tags: php, yii, swiftmailer

I am trying to use a custom class I have created to send out mail so I can keep the controller files thin. I created my custom class and put it in the components folder. I then added:

```
'sendMail' => array(
    'class'=>'application.components.SendMail.',
),
```

underneath main components in my main config file.

This should allow me to access the class directly correct? I try using:

```
Yii::app()->SendMail->MailerConfirmation();
```

and:

```
Yii:app()->MailerConfirmation();
```

and all I end up with is errors.

Can anyone tell me how I include a custom component? Maybe I am doing this all wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First it should be:

```
'sendMail' => array(
    'class'=>'application.components.SendMail',
),
```

Notice the absence of dot in the end "SendMail" instead of "SendMail.". Also, this configuration expects that you have php file SendMail.php, in protected/components directory that is a class with name "SendMail" and that this component extends CApplicationComponent. The component id will be with lower first letter, eg `Yii::app()->sendMail` and this will return instance of "SendMail" class. I do not know what MailerConfirmation is, but if this is a method of SendMail object, then you should access it like `Yii::app()->sendMail->MailerConfirmation()`

If this doesn't help, then please post some code and post the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you are not going to set any component properties in the config file or use other CApplicationComponent features and your config file includes the default:

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),
```

You can put your SendMail.php class in the components directory and it will autoload by calling it via:

```
$mailer = new SendMail();
```

then call your methods via:

```
$mailer->MailerConfirmation();
```

if you do want to use [CApplicationComponent](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplicationComponent/), you may want to look [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/187/how-to-write-a-simple-application-component) or [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/13280-how-to-create-hello-world-component/page__p__65116#entry65116) for a couple examples, as well as the Yii tutorials.